# Not able to access protected fields or methods in the sub calls

Tags: java

My program is as below:

```
package pack1;

public class Parent {
 int i=0;
 protected j =1;
 public k = 2;
}

package pack2;

import pack1.Parent;
public class Child extends Parent {

 public static void main (String args[]) {
   Child c1 = new Child();
   c1.j = 100; // This is working fine

   Parent c2 = new Child();
   c2.j=200; // Compilation error

 }
}
```

my question is : why we are nor able to access the protected member in the parent class with "c2".

Comment: Why do you have inheritance between packages? you should reconsider your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

An answer that cannot be argued with is "because the spec says so":

```
A protected member of a base class is accessible in a derived class only if the access occurs through the derived class type.
```

you would have to make the members internal (or public).